# YAML Template use in Azure Devops Release Server 2019

Tags: azure-devops-server-2019

Can we create and use YAML Templates in Azure Devops Server 2019? If yes, please share useful links.

Comment: Do you need YAML for defining CI/CD Pipelines in Devops?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, YAML-based build pipelines are available in Azure DevOps Server. Automate your continuous integration pipeline using a YAML file checked into your repository. A complete reference for the YAML schema can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema?view=azure-devops&tabs=schema%2Cparameter-schema&viewFallbackFrom=vsts).

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/server/release-notes/azuredevops2019?view=azure-devops#configure-builds-using-yaml

Comment: Thanks Cece. I agree that it is available in Build Pipelines. Is it available to use in Release Pipelines in Azure Devops Server 2019 ?

Comment: Not yet, please check this link: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/365687/pipeline-as-code.html